# Postgresql 12 EXECUTE STATEMENT WITHIN IF STATEMENT raise syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL v12

I want to dynamically update column values of the table 
where the column names and values are given to other table

taget table

```
|key |A |B |C |D |E |
|k1  |N |N |N |N |N |
|k2  |N |N |N |N |N |
|k3  |N |N |N |N |N |
```

other table

```
|key|column_name|value|
|k1 |A          |3    |
|k2 |B          |2    |
|k2 |C          |1    |
```

What I want to do is to update target table as follows

```
|key |A |B |C |D |E |
|k1  |3 |N |N |N |N |
|k2  |N |2 |1 |N |N |
|k3  |N |N |N |N |N |
```

1. target table and other table is given, so it is impossible to modify table structure
2. I'm a newbie on sql.
3. I ran this query on postgresql v11 and it works, while it raise syntex error on v12

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upadate_func()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
  r table1%rowtype; 
  lr text; 
BEGIN 
  -- r is a structure that contains an element for each column in the select  list
  FOR r IN select * from table1 
LOOP 
lr := LOWER(r.item); 
EXECUTE 'IF ' || '''' || lr || '''' || ' IN (SELECT item FROM table2) THEN' || 
        ' UPDATE table3' || 
        ' SET ' || lr || ' = ' || r.value || 
        ' WHERE key = ' || '''' || r.key || '''' || 
        ' AND date1 = ' || 'CAST(' || '''' || r.date1 || '''' || ' AS TIMESTAMP)' || 
        ' AND datafmt = ' || '''' || r.datafmt || '''' || 
        ' AND date2 >= '|| 'CAST(' || '''' || r.date2 || '''' || ' AS TIMESTAMP);' || 
        ' END IF;'; 
END LOOP; 
END 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
SELECT upadate_func();
```

it raises error as follows

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"

and printed if statement works well

What's wrong?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL.

Comment: There is `case when` construct in SQL.

Comment: Then why it works well when if statement ran well without execute?

Comment: Then is the given codes runnable as replacing 'if..then..end if' to 'case when..then..end case' ?

Comment: The format of Postgres execute statement is "EXECUTE <SQL STATEMENT>. A SQL statement cannot start with IF, it cannot even include IF except within a literal.  IF ... EXECUTE works because IF is a valid plpgsql statement. As far as changing to CASE as  that cannot begin an sql statement either. You always have to keep in mind which of the 2 languages (SQL or plpgsql) your statements are valid the current state of your code.